# How to use apply functions with a POSIXlt object?

Tags: r, types, sapply

Heyo,

So I like using a functional style which might be the problem. But, I'm trying to take a `Date` object and get an arbitrary number of years back.

```
# The Date object that is the starting point
referencedate <- as.Date("2015-06-30")
# The function that returns n years back
nYearsBack <- function(x,n){
  x <- as.POSIXlt(x)
  x$year <- x$year-n
  as.Date(x)
}
# The vector of years back we want returned as dates
yearsgoingback <- c(0,3,5)
# The function that doesn't work = (
datesgoingback <- sapply(X = yearsgoingback, FUN = function(x) nYearsBack(referencedate,x))
```

which returns

```
[1] 16616 15521 14790
```

To then recast it I have to run:

```
as.Date(datesgoingback, origin = "1970-01-01")
```

This raises the questions: Why do I need to do a further step of having to recast the integer into a `Date` object?

I thought maybe it was a sapply, vapply difference but even when I run the above code using `vapply` with `FUN.VALUE = Sys.time()` then it yields the same integer result.

Is there a way to succinctly take a date (any kind that there may be) and an arbitrary vector of integers and return a vector of the years back from the input date?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: This looks like a problem in how `sapply` simplifies its results. If you add `simplify=FALSE` as an argument to `sapply`, the expected results are back (unfortunately, returned in a list).

Comment: So this works, I have to call `unlist` to put it into a vector. Is this the best solution?

Comment: If you have to do it this way, then yeah, unlist(sapply(...)). I hope there is a better way, but do not know it :)

Comment: I would skip POSIXlt objects altogether and use `lubridate` package